# Prepending a string to the output of a BeautifulSoup scrape

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am scraping a forum page for posts and relevant links using BeautifulSoup.

The links on the page I want are in form `r"xx/res/[0-9]{5}.html$"`.

So far, so good finding them in my BeautifulSoup object, with the following link format returned when I `print`:  /xx/res/83071.html.

I now want to prepend the domain name 'http://website.com' to each result, and use the full url as the basis for further scraping.

My successful code looks like this:

```
url = 'http://website.com/xx/index.html'
res = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res, 'html.parser')

links = soup.select('a',{'href':re.compile(r"xx/res/[0-9]{5}.html$")})

for l in links:
    print(l['href'])
```

As a example, the following is printed to the console:

- /xx/res/83071.html
- /xx/res/81813.html
- /xx/res/92014.html
- /xx/res/92393.html

Hoping to get some help with the correct syntax to concatenate the prepended string to the output.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for you:-

```
url = 'http://website.com/xx/index.html'
res = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res, 'html.parser')

links = soup.select('a',{'href':re.compile(r"xx/res/[0-9]{5}.html$")})

for l in links:
    print ('http://website.com'+l['href'])
```

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it.

Comment: @runDiomedes If you think it works for you , you should accept it by clicking on right click button.Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it.  I personally like the string.format method.

store the base url:

```
xx = 'base_url'
```

your print line would be:

```
print('/{}/{}'.format(xx, l['href']))
```

where {} gets replaced by .format to instead have the variables you feed into the parameters.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. I'll give it a whirl once the kid goes to bed!

Comment: Np, let me know how it goes. =)